# Sharepoint List losing item level permissions after adding permissions are granted

Tags: permissions, flow, item-level-permissions, sharepoint-permissions

I have multiple lists with specific item-level permissions.

Two different kinds:

1. The default "Users can only read/write items which they created" toggled on
2. Specific item-level permissions granted by using Flow (based on a set of rules, specific users are associated with each item and can only see/edit that ones).

Everything was working fine, but for some reason, all my item-level permissions broke for a user when I upgraded him to a "Design" permission on the lists. He lost access to all the items, including the ones he himself created and the ones where specific permissions were given to him with a flow.

How come granting more control permissions on a list deleted the item-level ones that he already had? Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's an expected behavior for item-level permission. Grating users **Design** permission at the site or list level overwrites item-level permission.

Here is [an article](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-enable-item-level-permissions-in-sharepoint/#:%7E:text=To%20enable%20Item%20Level%20Permissions%2C%20go%20to%20List%20Settings%20%3E%20Advanced,see%20Item%20Level%20Permissions%20section.) describing this behavior.

Comment: Hum, from what I read, this would mean the person with Design permissions would have access to everything... But right now, that person can't see any item on the list (not even the ones he created). Maybe I wasn't clear on the question

Comment: Using **Manage access**, can you check the user's permission at the item level as well as the list level?

Comment: Also, by any chance, are you removing users' existing permissions and then granting new permissions in your Flow?

Comment: The user had item level permissions for certain items, right now those have disappeared. He has 'Design' permission at list level, which should not grant him access to other items, as each item is only visible to 'Owners' and specific people

Comment: On the flow, yes, I firstly remove permissions and then add them. But I have not run it after making the change. I'm guessing it will fix the issue by regranting permissions to the specific items